# Use of CList<GroupData *, GroupData *> listname;

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, generic-list, clist

I have written a function

```
CList<GroupData *,GroupData *> funcationName(CString arg1,CString arg2);
```

I am connecting to database and adding database results in GroupData Bean class. like this:

```
GroupData* grpData;
grpData->setGRGRID(groupid);
```

after that I am adding grpData in CList grpList;

```
grpList.AddHead(grpData);
```

I am getting compilation error

> can not access private member of cobject class

in compiler generated file afxtempl.h.

My class have a public constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return a CList object in your function:

```
CList funcationName(CString arg1,CString arg2);
```

I think the best option for you will be to change the function signature like this:

```
void funcationName(CString arg1, CString arg2, CList<GroupData *,GroupData *> &listData);
```

Then, you will need to initialise an empty CList in the calling function and pass it as the third parameter to the above function